# Flip coin using function C++

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to create a program which would use a function to flip a coin, and using the Main() method, return the results of it landing on heads, tails, and its edge in a 2D array. There is a 40% chance of it landing on heads, 40% chance of it landing on tails, and a 20% chance of it landing on its edge.

I kind of have the function, but it does not change the number in the Main() method. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void coinToss();

int heads = 0, tails = 0, edge = 0;


int main(){
const int NUMROWS = 3;
const int NUMCOLS = 2;

srand(time(NULL));

coinToss();


cout << "Heads: " + heads << endl;   //just to check if function works properly

system("pause");
}

void coinToss(){
int flip = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++){
    flip = rand() % 10 + 1;
    if (flip < 4){
        heads++;
    } 
    else if (flip < 8){
        tails++;
    }
    else {
        edge++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: @John3136 I'm not sure if I'm using it right, but it's not giving me any errors...

Comment: Try changing `cout << "Heads: " + heads << endl;` to `cout << "Heads: " << heads << endl;`

Comment: @Laserbreath suddenly I feel extremely stupid. Thank you for pointing the typo out.

Comment: @Frog6666 No problem, it's often the smallest things which end up being the most frustrating problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Your output line isn't correct:

```
cout << "Heads: " + heads << endl;
```

This is the same as

```
cout << ("Heads: " + heads) << endl;
```

which is the same as

```
cout << &("Heads: "[heads]) << endl;
```

which probably ends up with some kind of garbage due to `heads` being larger than seven. Instead, you have to use `<<`:

```
cout << "Heads: " << heads << endl;
```

#### Remarks

- Don't [use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- If possible, use the C++11 `<random>` library instead of `<cstdlib>`'s `rand`.
- Try to avoid global variables.
- Head over to [CR.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get further feedback as soon as you have a working program.